# How do I secure the bottom of vinyl siding before work is complete?

Tags: vinyl-siding

I've got some repair work to do that involves removing the bottom 4 or 5 feet of vinyl siding. I think, typically, work would start from the bottom and work up, and if I was done for the day all the pieces would be interlocked and the top edge would be nailed, so no problems walking away overnight.

In my case, I've got to split the siding and strip down, and this means the bottom edge of the siding is now free to flap about when the (strong) winds come in tonight.

How do I prevent the siding from getting damaged? I was thinking I could install a starter strip and re-fasten the siding to that, but it seems like an awful lot of work for a relatively short period of time. If that's the answer though that's fine; I'm just looking to see how this scenario would normally be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're expecting storms or high winds, it's not really an issue. Even if it flutters a bit it won't make a lot of noise.

Otherwise, a few strips of scrap plywood screwed gently to the wall sheathing and lapped over the siding panel will do. It doesn't need to be sophisticated.